# Ktor returns 404 instead 405 for defined endpoint

Tags: kotlin, ktor

```kotlin
@Resource("/")
internal object Root

@Resource("articles")
internal data class Articles(val parent: Root = Root)

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(CIO, port = 8080){
        install(Resources)
        routing {
            get<Root> {
                call.respondText("articles/")
            }
            get<Articles> {
                call.respondText("articles list")
            }
        }
    }.start(true)
}
```

when I call `PUT` on `/`I get `405 Method Not Allowed` error, but when I call `PUT` on `/articles` I get `404 Not Found` error instead of 405.

Is there a workaround to fix this?
I found the same question in the ktor GitHub issue but that was closed without a solution
https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/649

Comment: This is a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-6149. Thank you. Unfortunately, I can't find a workaround.

Comment: This is actually an expected behavior because 405 can be detected only for the constant paths.